# Twitter Api: get tweets with links

Tags: twitter

I'm building a website on which tweets from a certain user should be displayed. I know how to display the tweets using the user_timeline function from the twitter api, but these tweets are raw text tweets. Is there also a method to get the tweets in html with all the links already there? I couldn't find one myself but perhaps you do know one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Tweet Entities. See the Twitter API documentation for more information.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

Comment: can we add include_entities=true, as true parameter in twitter.getUserTimeline method, or any else ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [this helper function by Dustin Diaz](http://dustindiaz.com/linkified-tweets) to make a tweet fetched programmatically to look as it would on Twitter.

Update: [Here is a complete code sample that makes use of the above function](http://www.queness.com/post/8567/create-a-dead-simple-twitter-feed-with-jquery).

Comment: Link to this blog post looks promising, but the link within the post to actually download the source of what he's talking about are broken.

Comment: @MickByrne I updated my answer with a link to a code sample that uses this helper function & has the source.

Comment: Your link to the twitter widget is missing http://www.dustindiaz.com/basement/ify.html